# ORACLE Trigger printing related row

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a trigger that's purpose is to check the activity of the newly inserted row and print out a message if the activity already is in the table. The message prints the new row being added as well as a row in which already had that activity. I am able to print the row and that there is a duplicate but can't figure out how to initialize the values of the duplicated row and then print that.

trigger:

```
create or replace trigger insertActivities
before insert
on ACTIVITIES
for EACH row
declare
n int;
otherName varchar(30);
otherActivity varchar(30);
otherMinutes varchar(30);

begin
select Count(*)
into n
from ACTIVITIES
where Activity = :NEW.Activity;

if n>0 then 
dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate activity. New Name: ' || :NEW.Name || ' New Activity: '||    :NEW.Activity
|| ' New Minutes: '|| :NEW.Minutes || ' Other Name: ' || otherName || ' Other Activity: ' ||  otherActivity
|| 'Other Minutes: '|| otherMinutes);
end if;

END;
```

I know the 'other' variables are wrong, they are kind of place holders until I can figure out how to properly do it. Thanks.

Comment: And how would that behave in case of concurrent inserts ? No, seriously, isn't really any way of doing that using an `UNIQUE` index ?

Comment: tbh its for a class and really doesn't need to have complete logic, simply just able to do what I asked of it. I see what you are saying however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the "uniqueness" of your *activities*:

```
select Count(*),max(name),max(minutes)
into n, otherName, otherMinute
from ACTIVITIES
where Activity = :NEW.Activity; -- <-- is this an unique key ???
```

Using the aggregate function `MAX` will allow you to query your columns at the same time than counting.

You can go for a `GROUP BY` clause instead of using aggregate function. I don't know which one would be the nicest.

If your activities are *not* unique, you will have to loop through a cursor if you want to log all the "duplicates".

---

However, as I said in a comment, this might not behave as you expected it in case of concurrent inserts of the "same" activity. In that case, it is quite possible (depending your isolation level) that both insert will be executed without none of them detecting the "duplicate".

Comment: for the purposed of this assignment this works perfectly, thanks. I knew there was an easy way to "assign" those variables but couldn't think of it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got your question wrong, but do you just mean

```
select *
from ACTIVITIES
where Activity = :NEW.Activity
  and rowid!=:new.rowid;
```